# how to fix the error over notification in android?

Tags: android

i have created a radio player app with notification but when the user clicked on notification it redirected to main activity but it creates the page two times with player and playing twice

My notification:

```
 private void initNotification() {

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mukil)
                        .setContentTitle("My notification")
                        .setContentText("Hello World!");
// Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
// The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
// started Activity.
// This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
// your application to the Home screen.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());

    }
```

My Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    private ImageView control;

    /**
     * help to toggle between play and pause.
     */
    private boolean playPause;
     AudioManager audioManager;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, media;

    /**
     * remain false till media is not completed, inside OnCompletionListener make it true.
     */
    private boolean intialStage = true;
    String[] titles = {
            "Ippadikku Idhayam",
            "Akilam 360",
            "Cine Pattarai",
            "Palsuvai Thoranam",
            "Pesum Noolagam",
            "Lollu Cafe",
            "Kavi Saagaram",
            "Aa muthal Akk",
            "Thiraicholai",
            "Kathamba Saaral",
            "Paarkatha Pakkangal",
            "Pagadi Panna Porom",

    };

    public static  final String[] fromtime = new String[]{"10:30","12:30","14:30","16:30","18:30","20:30","22:30","24:30","02:30","04:30","06:30","08:30"};

    public static  final String[] totime = new String[]{"12:30","14:30","16:30","18:30","20:30","22:30","24:30","02:30","04:30","06:30","08:30","10:30"};



    Integer[] images = {
            R.drawable.ipadikku_idhayam,
            R.drawable.akilam_360,
            R.drawable.cine_pattarai,
            R.drawable.palsuvai_thoranam,
            R.drawable.pesum_noolagam,
            R.drawable.lollu_cafe,
            R.drawable.kavi_saagaram,
            R.drawable.aa_muthal_akk,
            R.drawable.thiraicholai,
            R.drawable.kathamba_saaral,
            R.drawable.paarkatha_pakkangal,
            R.drawable.pagadi_panna_porom,

    };

    ListView list,lvshow;
    List<Program> rowItems;
    int  iImageId;
    String sTitle,sFrom,sTo ;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    SeekBar seekbar;
    ImageView speaker,mute;

    AdapAdapter Adapadapter;
    UpcomingAdapter upcomingAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> iTitle = null;
    ArrayList<String> sQuantity = null;
    ArrayList<String> sQuantity1 = null;
    ArrayList<String> sImageID = null;

    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    //private static final String TOAST_TEXT = "Test ads are being shown. "
       //     + "To show live ads, replace the ad unit ID in res/values/strings.xml with your own ad unit ID.";


    private static final String TOAST_TEXT = "Smartah Kelunga Ungal MukilFM";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        // Toasts the test ad message on the screen. Remove this after defining your own ad unit ID.
        Toast.makeText(this, TOAST_TEXT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        initNotification();






         speaker = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.speaker);
        mute = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mute);

        seekbar =  (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {


                                                   audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, i, 0);
                                               }

                                               @Override
                                               public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                                               }

                                               @Override
                                               public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


                                               }



       /* ImageView upButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.control1);
        upButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

//To increase media player volume
                audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
            }
        });

        ImageView downButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.control2);
        downButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

//To decrease media player volume
                audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
            }
        });*/

       });

        db =openOrCreateDatabase("MukilProgram", Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS proname(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,ImageID INTEGER,Title TEXT,FromTiming INTEGER,ToTiming INTEGER);");

        rowItems = new ArrayList<Program>();
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            Program item = new Program(images[i], titles[i],fromtime[i],totime[i]);
            rowItems.add(item);
        }




        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM proname;");


        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        lvshow = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvshow);

        // listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        final ProgramAdapter adapter = new ProgramAdapter(this,rowItems, false);
        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            Program rowItem = (Program) adapter.getItem(i);

            iImageId = rowItem.getImageId();
            sTitle = rowItem.getTitle();
            sFrom = rowItem.getFromtime();
            sTo = rowItem.getTotime();

            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO proname (ImageID,Title,FromTiming,ToTiming) VALUES(" + iImageId + ",'" + sTitle + "','" + sFrom + "','" + sTo + "');");

        }


        final Cursor cView = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM proname WHERE FromTiming <= time('now', 'localtime')\n" + "" +
                "AND ToTiming >= time('now', 'localtime')\n" + "ORDER BY FromTiming LIMIT 1", null);
        if (cView.getCount() > 0) {

            sImageID = new ArrayList<String>();
            iTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
            sQuantity = new ArrayList<String>();
            sQuantity1 = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (cView.moveToNext()) {

                sImageID.add(cView.getString(1));
                iTitle.add(cView.getString(2));
                sQuantity.add(cView.getString(3));
                sQuantity1.add(cView.getString(4));

                Adapadapter = new AdapAdapter(MainActivity.this, sImageID, iTitle, sQuantity, sQuantity1);
                lvshow.setAdapter(Adapadapter);
            }

        }

        final Cursor cView1 = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM proname WHERE FromTiming > time('now', 'localtime')\n" + "ORDER BY FromTiming LIMIT 3", null);


        if (cView1.getCount() > 0) {

            sImageID = new ArrayList<String>();
            iTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
            sQuantity = new ArrayList<String>();
            sQuantity1 = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (cView1.moveToNext()) {

                sImageID.add(cView1.getString(1));
                iTitle.add(cView1.getString(2));
                sQuantity.add(cView1.getString(3));
                sQuantity1.add(cView1.getString(4));

                upcomingAdapter = new UpcomingAdapter(MainActivity.this, sImageID, iTitle, sQuantity, sQuantity1);
                list.setAdapter(upcomingAdapter);
            }

        }


            media = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mukil_master_jingle);


        control = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.control);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        control.setOnClickListener(pausePlay);
        control.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
        media.setLooping(true);

        if (intialStage) {
            new Player()
                    .execute("http://streaming.shoutcast.com/MUKILFMRADIO");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //Display alert message when back button has been pressed
        ViewDialog alert = new ViewDialog();
        alert.showDialog(this, "Are you really want to exit ?");

    }


    public class ViewDialog {

        public void showDialog(Activity activity, String msg) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.exitdialog);
            dialog.show();
            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_dialog);
            text.setText(msg);

            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btyes);
            Button dialogButton1 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btno);
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                    media.stop();
                    media.reset();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();


                }
            });
            dialogButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }

    }

    private View.OnClickListener pausePlay = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (playPause) {
                control.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                new Player().cancel(true);
                media.stop();
                media.reset();
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                media.stop();

                playPause = false;
            } else {
                control.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
                if (intialStage) {
                    new Player()
                            .execute("http://streaming.shoutcast.com/MUKILFMRADIO");
                } else {
                    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                }
                playPause = true;
            }


        }
    };

    /**
     * preparing mediaplayer will take sometime to buffer the content so prepare it inside the background thread and starting it on UI thread.
     *
     * @author piyush
     */

    class Player extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        private ProgressDialog progress;

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Boolean prepared;
            try {

                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(params[0]);




                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        intialStage = true;
                        playPause = false;
                        control.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                    }
                });
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                prepared = true;
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("IllegarArgument", e.getMessage());
                prepared = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                prepared = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                prepared = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                prepared = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return prepared;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (progress.isShowing()) {
                progress.cancel();
            }
            Log.d("Prepared", "//" + result);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            media.stop();

            intialStage = false;
        }

        public Player() {
            progress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            this.progress.setMessage("Buffering...");
            media.start();
        }
    }
    public  void mute1(View v){

        speaker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mute.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        mediaPlayer.setVolume(0,0);
        media.setVolume(0,0);
        seekbar.setClickable(false);
        seekbar.setFocusable(false);
        seekbar.setEnabled(false);

    }
    public  void speaker1(View v){

        speaker.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mute.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mediaPlayer.setVolume(1,1);
        media.setVolume(1,1);
        seekbar.setClickable(true);
        seekbar.setFocusable(true);
        seekbar.setEnabled(true);

    }

    private void initNotification() {

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mukil)
                        .setContentTitle("My notification")
                        .setContentText("Hello World!");
// Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

// The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
// started Activity.
// This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
// your application to the Home screen.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());

    }



    // Cancel Notification
    private void cancelNotification() {
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
        mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: try to use `singleTask` in your application launch mode.

Comment: i cant understand

Comment: Im a new developer

Comment: Yeah i have done but it doesnt wrks

Comment: hemm..weird..show your main activity code